Role of time embedding in flow matching
I was going through the flow matching paper by Lipmann and others. I understood the paper fairly well. I was also looking at the code for the same over here. One thing I did not understand in the code is the computation of a time embedding to compute the velocity field. Why is it necessary to incorporate a time embedding?

you want xt=xt-1+f(xt-1), thus you need to tell the net the “t” term

Thank you, this clears it up for me. I missed this for some reason. You can type this up as the answer, and I will be happy to mark it as accepted.

Usually in CNF you want to learn a vector field network $\mathcal{v^t(x)}$, which with some abuse of notation, can be red as $\mathcal{v(x|t)}$, so wither you create a network for each time (pretty expensive), or you hope that a network can learn the time-conditional vector field, thus you feed the net the time, so that it knows which vector field you want
